# JS reduce - sum only array lengths in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, reduce

I have the following data structure:

```
const arr = [    
    {key: 0, x: [], y: []},
    {key: 0, x: [], y: []}
]
```

I want to check if all arrays are empty, I have how can I do this using reduce? My code so far:

```
arr.reduce((count, acc) => {
    return acc !== 'key' ? count + acc.length : count
}, 0)
```

Comment: which property do you like to check?

Comment: Do you want to check length of `x` and `y` array?

Comment: I want to sum the length of all arrays

Comment: Is it  *really* just `x` & `y` or are there more properties which are arrays?

Comment: what do you want length or to know if all are zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take `key` out of the object and check all length for having zero.

```js
const
    array = [{ key: 0, x: [], y: [] }, { key: 0, x: [], y: [] }],
    allZero = array.every(({ key, ...o }) =>
        Object.values(o).every(({ length }) => !length));

console.log(allZero);
```

Summing

```js
const
    array = [{ key: 0, x: [], y: [] }, { key: 0, x: [], y: [] }],
    sum = array.reduce((s, { key, ...o }) =>
        Object.values(o).reduce((t, { length }) => t + length, s), 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

`reduce` is a bit of a clunky way to do this, and you're loopin over the items in the array, not the keys as (I think) you expected.

Use `Array.every` instead:

```js
const arr = [    
    {key: 0, x: [], y: []},
    {key: 0, x: [], y: []}
]

const arr2 = [    
    {key: 0, x: [1,2,3], y: []},
    {key: 0, x: [], y: []}
]

function areAllEmpty(a){
    return a.every(i => i.x.length == 0 && i.y.length == 0); 
}

console.log(areAllEmpty(arr));
console.log(areAllEmpty(arr2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `acc` will be the object in the array, you should check the object properties which are arrays. Use `Object.values` for this purpose, as well as another `reduce` for the arrays inside each object, and exclude `key`:

```js
const arr = [    
    {key: 0, x: [], y: []},
    {key: 0, x: [], y: []}
];

const res = arr.reduce((a, { key, ...c }) => a + Object.values(c).reduce((e, { length: f }) => e + f, 0), 0);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` on `Object.values` to get only array values. And then `flat()` and add the length to result

```js
const arr = [    
    {key: 0, x: [], y: []},
    {key: 0, x: [], y: []}
]

let res = arr.reduce((count, acc) => {
    return count + Object.values(acc).filter(x => x.constructor === Array).flat().length
}, 0)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sum **only arrays' lengths** in object using `Array.reduce()`:

```js
const arr = [    
    {key: 0, x: [], y: [], abc: "hsgg" },
    {key: 0, x: [1, 2, 3, 4], y: [1, 2]}
];

const c = arr.reduce((count, obj) => {
    Object.values(obj).forEach(v => {
      if(Array.isArray(v)) count += v.length;
    });
    return count;
}, 0);

console.log(c);
```

Note that in the other answers **strings' lengths are also counted**

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) is the better option. You can iterate over all the values of the objects and test to see if they're arrays and, if they are, return `false` if they're not empty. `every` will stop *as soon as it finds a non-empty array*, or end the of the iteration, whichever comes first.

```js
const arr = [    
  {key: 0, x: [], y: []},
  {key: 0, x: [], y: []}
];

const arr2 = [    
  {key: 0, x: [], y: [1]},
  {key: 0, x: [], y: []}
];

const allEmpty = (arr) => arr.every(el => {
  for (let v of Object.values(el)) {
    if (Array.isArray(v) && v.length > 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
});

console.log(allEmpty(arr));
console.log(allEmpty(arr2));
```